# In TeamCity, is there a way to list all NuGet packages used by all projects?

Tags: nuget, teamcity

Does anyone know of a way to aggregate all of the NuGet packages used for all of the most recent builds on a TeamCity server?

For each build in TeamCity there's a tab that shows what NuGet packages were used by that build:

[image: https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/08/nuget-package-restore-with-teamcity/]

That's great, but we would like to find dependencies for all projects without manually visiting each of the build pages.

Answer (score 17):

This URL returns an XML with the top 100 NuGet packages on the server. Use Internet Explorer to see the list of available packages. Other browsers display the raw XML.

```
http://TEAMCITY_SERVER_ADDRESS/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages()
```

To get all versions of a specific package

```
http://TEAMCITY_SERVER_ADDRESS/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?Id='PACKAGE_NAME'
```

Comment: That looks like it has potential. Is there any more documentation for the Packages() endpoint?  
It seems to return the top 100 in alphabetical order. It might be closer to what I need if it's possible to sort by DownloadCount or VersionDownloadCount.

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation on the feature. Maybe someone can help us out.